# Refresh periodically textarea with session attribute (JQuery, Java)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to update periodically the contents of an HTML textarea with the contents of a session attribute. The reason is because I'm using a servlet which takes a lot of time so process a reply, however I want to show in the textarea what is occuring while processing. My code is as follows:

```
        <form action="ClearOutput" method="post">
            <textarea id="console" name="console" rows="10" cols="100" readonly="readonly">
                ${sessionScope.console}
            </textarea>
               <script>
                window.onload = setupRefresh;
                function setupRefresh()
                {
                    setInterval("refreshBlock();",1000);
                }
                function refreshBlock()
                {
                    $('#console').text('${console}');
                }                   
            </script>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="clearOutput" value="Clear Output"/>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I'm using jQuery, as can be seen. Why does not my textarea update with the attribute (console) contents?

Comment: Consider looking for documentation for the proper usage of setInterval ;)

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval(refreshBlock,1000);` You need to pass a function. You dont need to invoke it there, too.

Comment: you are right, I modified the setInterval call, however it still does not work, seems that $console keeps the session attribute's contents from the first time it's executed, but the contents are never updated in the jsp, however the contents of attribute console are modified after submitting the form, in the servlet.

Comment: The problem is the console session attribute, which seems not to be updated after the first time :(

Comment: So that isnt really a HTML/JS problem is it ;)